# Different city name in DS-2019 and passport

Tags: usa, paperwork, j1-visas

Place of birth in DS-2019 and Passport is different. City name A is on the DS-2019, and village name B is on the passport.

Is it required to have the same place of birth on DS-2019 and passport?

Emergency answer please...

Comment: For what purpose are you asking whether it's required?  The visa application?  The actual travel to the US?  Something else?  Also, how did the DS-2019 come to be different from the passport?

Comment: On my ds2019 form, the place of birth says Hatay, but on the passport it says Antakya.  Antakya is a district of Hatay. In this case, will I have a problem during the appointment?  Or does it need to be fixed?  I don't have enough time to change the appointment only 3 days left.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for an emergency answer, I'll post this not terribly definitive answer in the hope that it will reduce your anxiety.

It's probably ok.  As an example, someone born in Chelsea might be said to be born in Chelsea, in London, in England, in Britain, or in the United Kingdom.  If some documents say "London" and others say "Chelsea," it's not going to be a problem.

In case it helps: even US passports used to list only the state in which a person was born, and now they list the city or town (including the state).